# start padding from RowsSupportFragment in tv leanback

Tags: leanback

[image: l]

is there any way to remove start padding from RowsSupportFragment as shown in arrows

following style does not remove start padding.

```
<style name="SearchTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Leanback.Browse">
    <item name="rowHeaderDockStyle">@style/RowHeaderDock</item>
    <item name="rowHorizontalGridStyle">@style/HorizentalGridStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="RowHeaderDock">
    <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
</style>
<style name="HorizentalGridStyle" parent="Widget.Leanback.Row.HorizontalGridView">
    <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: How did you made the side nav menu? Is it implemented inside activity or fragment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this statement to your `dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="lb_browse_padding_start">0dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

*using custome list row presenter*

```
class CustomListRowPresenter : ListRowPresenter(FocusHighlight.ZOOM_FACTOR_NONE, true) {

override fun initializeRowViewHolder(holder: RowPresenter.ViewHolder) {
    super.initializeRowViewHolder(holder)
    val vh = (holder as ViewHolder)
    val mContainerViewHolder =
        (RowPresenter.ViewHolder::class.java).getDeclaredField("mContainerViewHolder")
    mContainerViewHolder.isAccessible = true
    val viewHolder = mContainerViewHolder.get(vh) as Presenter.ViewHolder
    val nonOverlappingLinearLayout =
        (viewHolder.view as ViewGroup).children.find { it is NonOverlappingLinearLayout }
    if (nonOverlappingLinearLayout != null) {
        val left = 0
        val right = nonOverlappingLinearLayout.right
        val top = nonOverlappingLinearLayout.top
        val bottom = nonOverlappingLinearLayout.bottom
        nonOverlappingLinearLayout.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom)
    }
    val headerHolder = vh.headerViewHolder
    headerHolder.selectLevel
    val field = vh::class.java.getDeclaredField("mPaddingLeft")
    field.isAccessible = true
    field.set(vh, 0)
}
```

}

Comment: how to add in fragment?